# Javascript.In an array, how to find how much numbers change by each time?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array within an array with dates and an amount
`var finances = [ ['jan', 25000], ['feb', 22000], ['mars', 21000] ]` 
I want to find out by how much the number changes each month. Then I want to find the difference between this change each month and add it up. I thought I had it but it is not working as I thought and I am really lost. I think I may be trying it completely the wrong way. Sorry if this is poorly worded.

I want to get the average of the amount the number changes by each month. At the moment I ma getting NAN.

```
var finances = [
    ['Jan-2010', 867884],
    ['Feb-2010', 984655],
    ['Mar-2010', 322013],
    ['Apr-2010', -69417],
    ['May-2010', 310503],
    ['Jun-2010', 522857],
    ['Jul-2010', 1033096],
    ['Aug-2010', 604885],
    ['Sep-2010', -216386],
    ['Oct-2010', 477532],
    ['Nov-2010', 893810],
    ['Dec-2010', -80353],
    ['Jan-2011', 779806],
    ['Feb-2011', -335203],
    ['Mar-2011', 697845],
    ['Apr-2011', 793163],
    ['May-2011', 485070],
    ['Jun-2011', 584122],
    ['Jul-2011', 62729],
    ['Aug-2011', 668179],
    ['Sep-2011', 899906],
    ['Oct-2011', 834719],
    ['Nov-2011', 132003],
    ['Dec-2011', 309978],
    ['Jan-2012', -755566],
    ['Feb-2012', 1170593],
    ['Mar-2012', 252788],
    ['Apr-2012', 1151518],
    ['May-2012', 817256],
    ['Jun-2012', 570757],
    ['Jul-2012', 506702],
    ['Aug-2012', -1022534],
    ['Sep-2012', 475062],
    ['Oct-2012', 779976],
    ['Nov-2012', 144175],
    ['Dec-2012', 542494],
    ['Jan-2013', 359333],
    ['Feb-2013', 321469],
    ['Mar-2013', 67780],
    ['Apr-2013', 471435],
    ['May-2013', 565603],
    ['Jun-2013', 872480],
    ['Jul-2013', 789480],
    ['Aug-2013', 999942],
    ['Sep-2013', -1196225],
    ['Oct-2013', 268997],
    ['Nov-2013', -687986],
    ['Dec-2013', 1150461],
    ['Jan-2014', 682458],
    ['Feb-2014', 617856],
    ['Mar-2014', 824098],
    ['Apr-2014', 581943],
    ['May-2014', 132864],
    ['Jun-2014', 448062],
    ['Jul-2014', 689161],
    ['Aug-2014', 800701],
    ['Sep-2014', 1166643],
    ['Oct-2014', 947333],
    ['Nov-2014', 578668],
    ['Dec-2014', 988505],
    ['Jan-2015', 1139715],
    ['Feb-2015', 1029471],
    ['Mar-2015', 687533],
    ['Apr-2015', -524626],
    ['May-2015', 158620],
    ['Jun-2015', 87795],
    ['Jul-2015', 423389],
    ['Aug-2015', 840723],
    ['Sep-2015', 568529],
    ['Oct-2015', 332067],
    ['Nov-2015', 989499],
    ['Dec-2015', 778237],
    ['Jan-2016', 650000],
    ['Feb-2016', -1100387],
    ['Mar-2016', -174946],
    ['Apr-2016', 757143],
    ['May-2016', 445709],
    ['Jun-2016', 712961],
    ['Jul-2016', -1163797],
    ['Aug-2016', 569899],
    ['Sep-2016', 768450],
    ['Oct-2016', 102685],
    ['Nov-2016', 795914],
    ['Dec-2016', 60988],
    ['Jan-2017', 138230],
    ['Feb-2017', 671099]
];

for (var i = 0; i < finances.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < finances[i].length; j++) {
        if (typeof finances[i][j] !== 'string') {
            onlyNumbers.push(finances[i][j])
            console.log(finances[i][j]);
            amountTotal = amountTotal + (finances[i][j]);

        }

    }

}
```

```
for (var k = 1; k < onlyNumbers.length; k++) {
    monthlyChanges.push(onlyNumbers[k] - onlyNumbers[k - 1]);
}
for (var m = 1; m < monthlyChanges.length; m++) {
    monthlyChangesArray.push(monthlyChanges[m] - monthlyChanges[m - 1]);
    monthlyChangesAmount = monthlyChangesAmount + (monthlyChangesArray[m]);

}



console.log(onlyNumbers);
console.log(amountTotal);
console.log(monthlyChanges);
console.log(monthlyChangesArray);
console.log(monthlyChangesAmount);
```

Comment: Use one loop from 0 to length-2, inclusive.  Subtract item[i] from item[i + 1]

Comment: So what is not working? Please provide a complete runnable example, with example input data, what you would like to get, and what you get instead.

Comment: Please update your question with the expected behavior. What you input (have) and what you expect to get as the output. So that it's easy to give you an answer.

Comment: I have added some more to the question. I do not have a runnable example as I can't work it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go through every item except the first, and find the difference between it and the previous item.

```js
var finances = [
    ['Jan-2010', 867884],
    ['Feb-2010', 984655],
    ['Mar-2010', 322013],
    ['Apr-2010', -69417],
    ['May-2010', 310503],
    ['Jun-2010', 522857],
    ['Jul-2010', 1033096],
    ['Aug-2010', 604885],
    ['Sep-2010', -216386],
    ['Oct-2010', 477532],
    ['Nov-2010', 893810],
    ['Dec-2010', -80353],
    ['Jan-2011', 779806],
    ['Feb-2011', -335203],
    ['Mar-2011', 697845],
    ['Apr-2011', 793163],
    ['May-2011', 485070],
    ['Jun-2011', 584122],
    ['Jul-2011', 62729],
    ['Aug-2011', 668179],
    ['Sep-2011', 899906],
    ['Oct-2011', 834719],
    ['Nov-2011', 132003],
    ['Dec-2011', 309978],
    ['Jan-2012', -755566],
    ['Feb-2012', 1170593],
    ['Mar-2012', 252788],
    ['Apr-2012', 1151518],
    ['May-2012', 817256],
    ['Jun-2012', 570757],
    ['Jul-2012', 506702],
    ['Aug-2012', -1022534],
    ['Sep-2012', 475062],
    ['Oct-2012', 779976],
    ['Nov-2012', 144175],
    ['Dec-2012', 542494],
    ['Jan-2013', 359333],
    ['Feb-2013', 321469],
    ['Mar-2013', 67780],
    ['Apr-2013', 471435],
    ['May-2013', 565603],
    ['Jun-2013', 872480],
    ['Jul-2013', 789480],
    ['Aug-2013', 999942],
    ['Sep-2013', -1196225],
    ['Oct-2013', 268997],
    ['Nov-2013', -687986],
    ['Dec-2013', 1150461],
    ['Jan-2014', 682458],
    ['Feb-2014', 617856],
    ['Mar-2014', 824098],
    ['Apr-2014', 581943],
    ['May-2014', 132864],
    ['Jun-2014', 448062],
    ['Jul-2014', 689161],
    ['Aug-2014', 800701],
    ['Sep-2014', 1166643],
    ['Oct-2014', 947333],
    ['Nov-2014', 578668],
    ['Dec-2014', 988505],
    ['Jan-2015', 1139715],
    ['Feb-2015', 1029471],
    ['Mar-2015', 687533],
    ['Apr-2015', -524626],
    ['May-2015', 158620],
    ['Jun-2015', 87795],
    ['Jul-2015', 423389],
    ['Aug-2015', 840723],
    ['Sep-2015', 568529],
    ['Oct-2015', 332067],
    ['Nov-2015', 989499],
    ['Dec-2015', 778237],
    ['Jan-2016', 650000],
    ['Feb-2016', -1100387],
    ['Mar-2016', -174946],
    ['Apr-2016', 757143],
    ['May-2016', 445709],
    ['Jun-2016', 712961],
    ['Jul-2016', -1163797],
    ['Aug-2016', 569899],
    ['Sep-2016', 768450],
    ['Oct-2016', 102685],
    ['Nov-2016', 795914],
    ['Dec-2016', 60988],
    ['Jan-2017', 138230],
    ['Feb-2017', 671099]
];

function findChanges(data) {
  const changes = [];
  for (let i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    const curr = data[i], prev = data[i-1];
    changes.push([`(${prev[0]})_to_(${curr[0]})`, curr[1] - prev[1]])
  }
  return changes;
}

const changes = findChanges(finances);
const changesOfChanges = findChanges(changes);

document.getElementById("a").textContent = JSON.stringify(changes, null, 2)
document.getElementById("b").textContent = JSON.stringify(changesOfChanges, null, 2)
```

```html
<h1>Changes</h1>
<pre id="a"></pre>
<h1>Changes Of Changes</h1>
<pre id="b"></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can try to get array of monthly changes :

```
var finances = [
      ["Jan-2010", 867884],
      ["Feb-2010", 984655],
      ["Mar-2010", 322013],
      ["Apr-2010", -69417],
      ["May-2010", 310503],
      ["Jun-2010", 522857],
      ["Jul-2010", 1033096],
      ["Aug-2010", 604885],
      ["Sep-2010", -216386],
      ["Oct-2010", 477532],
      ["Nov-2010", 893810],
      ["Dec-2010", -80353],
      ["Jan-2011", 779806],
      ["Feb-2011", -335203],
      ["Mar-2011", 697845],
      ["Apr-2011", 793163],
      ["May-2011", 485070],
      ["Jun-2011", 584122],
      ["Jul-2011", 62729],
      ["Aug-2011", 668179],
      ["Sep-2011", 899906],
      ["Oct-2011", 834719],
      ["Nov-2011", 132003],
      ["Dec-2011", 309978],
      ["Jan-2012", -755566],
      ["Feb-2012", 1170593],
      ["Mar-2012", 252788],
      ["Apr-2012", 1151518],
      ["May-2012", 817256],
      ["Jun-2012", 570757],
      ["Jul-2012", 506702],
      ["Aug-2012", -1022534],
      ["Sep-2012", 475062],
      ["Oct-2012", 779976],
      ["Nov-2012", 144175],
      ["Dec-2012", 542494],
      ["Jan-2013", 359333],
      ["Feb-2013", 321469],
      ["Mar-2013", 67780],
      ["Apr-2013", 471435],
      ["May-2013", 565603],
      ["Jun-2013", 872480],
      ["Jul-2013", 789480],
      ["Aug-2013", 999942],
      ["Sep-2013", -1196225],
      ["Oct-2013", 268997],
      ["Nov-2013", -687986],
      ["Dec-2013", 1150461],
      ["Jan-2014", 682458],
      ["Feb-2014", 617856],
      ["Mar-2014", 824098],
      ["Apr-2014", 581943],
      ["May-2014", 132864],
      ["Jun-2014", 448062],
      ["Jul-2014", 689161],
      ["Aug-2014", 800701],
      ["Sep-2014", 1166643],
      ["Oct-2014", 947333],
      ["Nov-2014", 578668],
      ["Dec-2014", 988505],
      ["Jan-2015", 1139715],
      ["Feb-2015", 1029471],
      ["Mar-2015", 687533],
      ["Apr-2015", -524626],
      ["May-2015", 158620],
      ["Jun-2015", 87795],
      ["Jul-2015", 423389],
      ["Aug-2015", 840723],
      ["Sep-2015", 568529],
      ["Oct-2015", 332067],
      ["Nov-2015", 989499],
      ["Dec-2015", 778237],
      ["Jan-2016", 650000],
      ["Feb-2016", -1100387],
      ["Mar-2016", -174946],
      ["Apr-2016", 757143],
      ["May-2016", 445709],
      ["Jun-2016", 712961],
      ["Jul-2016", -1163797],
      ["Aug-2016", 569899],
      ["Sep-2016", 768450],
      ["Oct-2016", 102685],
      ["Nov-2016", 795914],
      ["Dec-2016", 60988],
      ["Jan-2017", 138230],
      ["Feb-2017", 671099],
    ];
    
    let result = finances.reduce((prev, curr, index, arr) => {
      arr[index + 1]
        ? prev.push([
            `${arr[index][0]} - ${arr[index + 1][0]}`,
            arr[index + 1][1] - arr[index][1],
          ])
        : 0;
      return prev;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).